# Source map file not being written using webpack and gulp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, webpack, source-maps

We are using webpack to bundle our JavaScript & jsx files and we use Gulp to run run webpack. We have specified the `devtool: 'source-map'` option and when gulp runs we see `bundle.js.map` being emitted, but when we look in the destination folder it is not there.  (`bundle.js` is there). Does anyone know what is happening here?

Here is our webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve('./cdn/source/javascript'),
    entry: ['./app'],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true}),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./cdn/distribution'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Here is our gulp task:

```
gulp.task('scripts', () => {
  del(['./cdn/distribution/*.js', './cdn/distribution/*.js.map']);

  var webpackconfigjs = require('./webpack.config.js');
  return gulp.src('./cdn/source/javascript/app.jsx')
    .pipe(webpack(webpackconfigjs))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./cdn/distribution'));
});
```

And this is the output we see:

```
[11:27:53] Using gulpfile D:\Code\mergeui\gulpfile.js
[11:27:53] Starting 'scripts'...
[11:27:59] Version: webpack 1.12.10
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js   273 kB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  2.21 MB       0  [emitted]  main
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Ever managed to find a solution?

Comment: See if this helps: extract del to `gulp.task('clean-scripts', ()=>del([...]));` and change the `scripts` task to: `gulp.task('scripts', ['clean-scripts'], () => {`.